# Query MySQL using JSP and Servlet POST method

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm not sure if I'm trying to "print" my result correctly.  What I'm trying to do is use JSP to take in the variable and then pass it to the servlet where it will query the database and then display the result.  I tested querying my database in a different java file and I had no trouble with that.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

JSP file:

```
<form method="post" action="HelloServlet"/>
Enter your name:<input name = "exName"/><br>

<input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

JAVA file (servlet):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {

        //response.setContentType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        java.sql.Connection con = null;
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/masters";  
        String user = "christine";
        String password = "password";

        try{
            String exName = request.getParameter("exName");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);  
            pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exercise_name ='"+exName+"';");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();  

            while (rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("description_txt");

                out.print(exName);
                out.print(name);
            }   
        }catch(SQLException ex){
        }finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null){
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (pst != null){
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (con != null){
                    con.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException ex){
            }           
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You're completely suppressing the `SQLException` being thrown. **Why?** Add `throw new ServletException(ex)` to the catch so that you get a nice error page with stack trace and all on em. Exceptions contain namely the whole answer to the problem.

Comment: (I'm still a beginner) I guess I didn't know that I'm suppressing the SQLException.  Would you mind pointing out where I'm doing that?  I don't quite understand.  Thank you.

Comment: You're catching the `SQLException` but not doing anything with it and continuning the code flow as if nothing special has happend. You should at least log/print it or in this case better rethrow it as `ServletException`, conform the Servlet API specification recommendation.

Comment: POSTed form values are attributes, use getAttribute instead of getParameter

Comment: Thank you both for the info!

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to change in your code.

As @BalusC mentioned do not suppress exception. Write exception to browser using `out.println(ex);` or `throw new ServletException(ex)`. This will help you in finding the cause of problem.

Add `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

As you are already using `PreparedStatement` use

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exercise_name =?");
pst.setString(1, exName);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik, I did make those changes, compiled and received: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  I looked up what that meant and what I found is that MySQL jdbc driver jar file is missing from the classpath.  When I searched on how to solve this problem, I read suggestions to download the JDBC driver.  I've already done that and placed it in my "library", and have "mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar" in there.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user2221016: You are wel-come. You may accept the hwlpful answer. This encourages the users on SO. :)

Comment: Oh, Sorry I wasn't clear... even with the JDBC driver in place, I was receiving that error.  Do you think that I'm missing something else?

Comment: After compiling, I was receiving the error: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" which I guess I don't understand why I'm receiving that message since I have the JDBC driver in my library.

Comment: @user2221016: Put `.jar` file under /WEB-INF/lib directory. Restart tomcat.

Comment: I placed the jar file under /WEB-INF/lib by via "Build
Path-->Configure Build Path-->Deployment Assembly" (instructions I
found online for Eclipse) and now I receiving a 404 Error.  Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: @user2221016: Then You should ask new question with details. No more comments please